# Running a CNTK model under a VS unit test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, cntk

I have trained a CNTK model using C#, and now I want to run test cases against a wrapper class so that we can detect problems if somebody replaces the model with one that doesn't perform as well, and additionally have a repeating comparison of the neural network against our old model.  However, when I try to run the test I get:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at CNTK.CNTKLibPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_CNTKLib(ExceptionDelegate applicationDelegate, ExceptionDelegate arithmeticDelegate, ExceptionDelegate divideByZeroDelegate, ExceptionDelegate indexOutOfRangeDelegate, ExceptionDelegate invalidCastDelegate, ExceptionDelegate invalidOperationDelegate, ExceptionDelegate ioDelegate, ExceptionDelegate nullReferenceDelegate, ExceptionDelegate outOfMemoryDelegate, ExceptionDelegate overflowDelegate, ExceptionDelegate systemExceptionDelegate)
   at CNTK.CNTKLibPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
...
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CNTK.CNTKLibPINVOKE' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Cntk.Core.CSBinding-2.3.1.dll': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)
```

I have gotten this same error from a stand-alone console app and fixed it by ensuring the console app and class library both build as x64.  I made the same changes to the test project, and additionally set the test architecture to x64 (Test > Test Settings > Default Processor Architecture > x64), but no dice.

I am using the GPU version of CNTK (2.3.1), though for the unit test context it should be using CPU.  I have verified that Cntk.Core.CSBinding-2.3.1.dll is present in the bin directory.

Any ideas out there?  Has anybody tried this?

Comment: I've had a very similar error when doing unit tests involving classes that required an entry in app.config to properly initialize. I don't know that you have exactly that issue, but this error almost always comes down to some difference between your main project and the test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using NUnit, I've seen this a lot. There comes a bunch of native DLLs with the CNTK package, which the test runner doesn't find, because the working directory is set to some temp directory, not to your output folder. My solution is to copy all necessary DLLs to the working directory every time the test start. I do this in the [SetUp] method of the [TestFixture] in question.

And if you're using a different test framework, maybe it has similar problems.

Comment: Thanks!  Not using NUnit, just default microsoft test infrastructure.  I guess the pInvoke is only aware of the working directory and not the bin directory.  Setting the current directory to the binary directory worked, though it's not great.  I'll look into doing the copy, as you suggest, or find out if it uses the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Instead of changing the working directory per @MartinAy's solution or copying a bunch of binaries per this solution, you can just add the binary folder to the PATH during TestInitialize:

`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")}{Path.PathSeparator}{binFolderPath}");`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, when I used NUnit. Adding the following code to the Test Setup, solved my issue.

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory;
}
```

Comment: I didn't have a TestContext.CurrentContext, but modifying Environment.CurrentDirectory to point at the bin folder did work for me.